# Subset of causal spacetime+Imprisonment Condition+Compact Closure -> Stably Causal spacetime?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity

My question arose after studying the article "John K. Beem: Conformal Changes and Geodesic Completeness". (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103899983) One of the results there is:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a causal spacetime which satisfies condition $N$. If $E$ is an open subset of $M$ with compact closure $\overline{E}$, then $(E,g)$ is stably causal.

To recall the necessary definitions:

For $(M,g)$ condition $N$ is satisfied, if for every compact subset $K \subset M$, there is no future inextendible nonspacelike curve which is totally future imprisoned in $K$.

$(E,g)$ is the metric $g$ restricted to the manifold $E\subset M$.

However I feel the proof of this is flawed, (The negation of stable causality is stated falsely in the proof of theorem 2, I think) yet the claim seems to be true. In fact even ignoring the condition $N$, I could not come up with a counterexample. Can anyone provide me with a counterexample? That is to answer the following question:

> Can there be a causal spacetime $(M,g)$ and an open subset $E \subset M$ with compact closure $\overline{E}$, such that $(E,g)$ is *not* stably causal?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Why do you think the negation of stable causality is stated incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit:* In Beem's article on Page 180 before the introduction of condition (N) he mentions Carter's example (see also Hawking, Ellis The large scale structure of space-time, p. 195, Fig. 39). There you should get your counterexample by $E=(t_1,t_2)\times S^1 \times S^2$.

Comment: Yes, that answers the question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh no! I just realized, that your example in fact does not seem to answer the question. Because the set E from your example indeed happens to be stably causal! (Because one can define a time function on E) Additionally you can see, that E is strongly causal, because there are no nearly closed non-spacelike curves completely contained in E. (They have to move around S^1 and therefor leave E)

Comment: I meant $E$ to be a rectangle before projecting, i.e., $E$ should "loop around" too. I will think about it and post more details.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @C_S, but unfortunately I still do not quite understand... My edition of the book doesn't have anything by the name of $\alpha$, but I assume you mean the lightlike curve whose endpoints are used for the definitions of $L_1$, $L_2$. That is the dotted line in the following picture: http://didaktik.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/files/stable-causality-example.jpg . I also tried to draw your suggestion of $E$, however I think I got you wrong here. Because the $E$ drawn in the picture is not compact. (for instance a sequence approaching $L_1$ has no limit)

Comment: No, the curve drawn is called $\alpha$. I think it is not readable well in the picture and you apparently mistook if for an $x$. But you are right I forgot to take the removal of $L_1, L_2$ into account.

Comment: Another try - see edited post.

Comment: I'm afraid, this example too does not work. Because indeed that ball would be stably causal (and hence strongly causal as well). The reason being: For every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ inside of $E$ you can find a curve similar to $\alpha$ starting and ending in $U$. **However**: This curve will leave $E$. So while $U$ is no causally convex neighborhood with respect to $M$, it is causally convex with respect to $E$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. As a subset of $M$, $E$ is not strongly causal. Of, course if you just consider $E$ than it is a subset of Minkowski space. But that is not what you asked, was it?

Comment: The manifold $(E,g)$ shall be considered as a spacetime, where $g$ means the restriction of the original metric to $E$. And as such $(E,g)$ is a subset of Minkowski space and also stably causal, you can easily define a time function on $E$. $E$ as a subset of $M$ is not _causally convex_, still the manifold $(E,g)$ is strongly causal. It seems you keep talking about causally convexity of $E$ (not about strong or stable causality), or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Yes, I got that now. It arose from the fact that strong causality can be defined for a subset of a space-time and for a space-time itself. So now I think the problem is not so easy, since one can have arbitrarily small globally hyperbolic (hence stably causal) open subsets $E$ in any (sufficiently smooth) space-time.

Comment: Hy! If your question is still open: I just saw that it is answered already in Beem's article. On page 180 before the introduction of condition (N) he mentions Carter's example (see also Hawking, Ellis The large scale structure of space-time, p. 195, Fig. 39).

Comment: Yes, the questions was still open, and I appreciate your answer very much.